# Getting v4l2rtspserver working on Raspian bookworm with High Resolution camera V1

Tags: raspbian, camera, video, rtsp

I have installed v4l2rtspserver on raspian (bookworm) using snap:

```
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install snapd
   sudo snap install core
   sudo snap install v412rtspserver
```

The install went great, but now I can't seem to open the right stream when I run the command:

```
   v4l2rtspserver -W 1920 -H 1080 -F 15 -P 8554 /dev/video0
```

I get this error:

```
[NOTICE] /home/pi/v4l2rtspserver/main.cpp:270
        Version:  live555 version:2023.11.30
[NOTICE] /home/pi/v4l2rtspserver/src/V4l2RTSPServer.cpp:37
        Create V4L2 Source.../dev/video0
[NOTICE] /home/pi/v4l2rtspserver/libv4l2cpp/src/V4l2Device.cpp:133
        driver:unicam capabilities:a5a00001 mandatory:4000001
[NOTICE] /home/pi/v4l2rtspserver/libv4l2cpp/src/V4l2Device.cpp:136
        /dev/video0 support capture
[NOTICE] /home/pi/v4l2rtspserver/libv4l2cpp/src/V4l2Device.cpp:138
        /dev/video0 support read/write
[NOTICE] /home/pi/v4l2rtspserver/libv4l2cpp/src/V4l2Device.cpp:139
        /dev/video0 support streaming
[ERROR] /home/pi/v4l2rtspserver/libv4l2cpp/src/V4l2Device.cpp:212
        /dev/video0: Cannot set pixelformat to:HEVC format is:YUYV
[ERROR] /home/pi/v4l2rtspserver/libv4l2cpp/src/V4l2Device.cpp:212
        /dev/video0: Cannot set pixelformat to:H264 format is:YUYV
[ERROR] /home/pi/v4l2rtspserver/libv4l2cpp/src/V4l2Device.cpp:212
        /dev/video0: Cannot set pixelformat to:MJPG format is:YUYV
[ERROR] /home/pi/v4l2rtspserver/libv4l2cpp/src/V4l2Device.cpp:212
        /dev/video0: Cannot set pixelformat to:JPEG format is:YUYV
[ERROR] /home/pi/v4l2rtspserver/libv4l2cpp/src/V4l2Device.cpp:212
        /dev/video0: Cannot set pixelformat to:NV12 format is:YUYV
[ERROR] /home/pi/v4l2rtspserver/libv4l2cpp/src/V4l2Device.cpp:83
        Cannot init device:/dev/video0
[NOTICE] /home/pi/v4l2rtspserver/libv4l2cpp/src/V4l2MmapDevice.cpp:141
VIDIOC_STREAMOFF: Bad file descriptor
VIDIOC_REQBUFS: Bad file descriptor
```

I know my camera is plugged in I get this output:

```
sudo v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video0 --list-formats-ext

ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
        Type: Video Capture

        [0]: 'YUYV' (YUYV 4:2:2)
                Size: Stepwise 16x16 - 16376x16376 with step 1/1
        [1]: 'UYVY' (UYVY 4:2:2)
                Size: Stepwise 16x16 - 16376x16376 with step 1/1
        [2]: 'YVYU' (YVYU 4:2:2)
                Size: Stepwise 16x16 - 16376x16376 with step 1/1
        [3]: 'VYUY' (VYUY 4:2:2)
                Size: Stepwise 16x16 - 16376x16376 with step 1/1
        [4]: 'RGBP' (16-bit RGB 5-6-5)
                Size: Stepwise 16x16 - 16376x16376 with step 1/1
        [5]: 'RGBR' (16-bit RGB 5-6-5 BE)
                Size: Stepwise 16x16 - 16376x16376 with step 1/1
        [6]: 'RGBO' (16-bit A/XRGB 1-5-5-5)
                Size: Stepwise 16x16 - 16376x16376 with step 1/1
        [7]: 'RGBQ' (16-bit A/XRGB 1-5-5-5 BE)
                Size: Stepwise 16x16 - 16376x16376 with step 1/1
        [8]: 'RGB3' (24-bit RGB 8-8-8)
                Size: Stepwise 16x16 - 16376x16376 with step 1/1
        [9]: 'BGR3' (24-bit BGR 8-8-8)
                Size: Stepwise 16x16 - 16376x16376 with step 1/1
        [10]: 'RGB4' (32-bit A/XRGB 8-8-8-8)
                Size: Stepwise 16x16 - 16376x16376 with step 1/1
        [11]: 'BA81' (8-bit Bayer BGBG/GRGR)
                Size: Stepwise 16x16 - 16376x16376 with step 1/1
        [12]: 'GBRG' (8-bit Bayer GBGB/RGRG)
                Size: Stepwise 16x16 - 16376x16376 with step 1/1
        [13]: 'GRBG' (8-bit Bayer GRGR/BGBG)
                Size: Stepwise 16x16 - 16376x16376 with step 1/1
        [14]: 'RGGB' (8-bit Bayer RGRG/GBGB)
                Size: Stepwise 16x16 - 16376x16376 with step 1/1
        [15]: 'pBAA' (10-bit Bayer BGBG/GRGR Packed)
                Size: Stepwise 16x16 - 16376x16376 with step 1/1
        [16]: 'BG10' (10-bit Bayer BGBG/GRGR)
                Size: Stepwise 16x16 - 16376x16376 with step 1/1
        [17]: 'pGAA' (10-bit Bayer GBGB/RGRG Packed)
                Size: Stepwise 16x16 - 16376x16376 with step 1/1
        [18]: 'GB10' (10-bit Bayer GBGB/RGRG)
                Size: Stepwise 16x16 - 16376x16376 with step 1/1
        [19]: 'pgAA' (10-bit Bayer GRGR/BGBG Packed)
                Size: Stepwise 16x16 - 16376x16376 with step 1/1
        [20]: 'BA10' (10-bit Bayer GRGR/BGBG)
                Size: Stepwise 16x16 - 16376x16376 with step 1/1
        [21]: 'pRAA' (10-bit Bayer RGRG/GBGB Packed)
                Size: Stepwise 16x16 - 16376x16376 with step 1/1
        [22]: 'RG10' (10-bit Bayer RGRG/GBGB)
                Size: Stepwise 16x16 - 16376x16376 with step 1/1
        [23]: 'pBCC' (12-bit Bayer BGBG/GRGR Packed)
                Size: Stepwise 16x16 - 16376x16376 with step 1/1
        [24]: 'BG12' (12-bit Bayer BGBG/GRGR)
                Size: Stepwise 16x16 - 16376x16376 with step 1/1
        [25]: 'pGCC' (12-bit Bayer GBGB/RGRG Packed)
                Size: Stepwise 16x16 - 16376x16376 with step 1/1
        [26]: 'GB12' (12-bit Bayer GBGB/RGRG)
                Size: Stepwise 16x16 - 16376x16376 with step 1/1
        [27]: 'pgCC' (12-bit Bayer GRGR/BGBG Packed)
                Size: Stepwise 16x16 - 16376x16376 with step 1/1
        [28]: 'BA12' (12-bit Bayer GRGR/BGBG)
                Size: Stepwise 16x16 - 16376x16376 with step 1/1
        [29]: 'pRCC' (12-bit Bayer RGRG/GBGB Packed)
                Size: Stepwise 16x16 - 16376x16376 with step 1/1
        [30]: 'RG12' (12-bit Bayer RGRG/GBGB)
                Size: Stepwise 16x16 - 16376x16376 with step 1/1
        [31]: 'pBEE' (14-bit Bayer BGBG/GRGR Packed)
                Size: Stepwise 16x16 - 16376x16376 with step 1/1
        [32]: 'BG14' (14-bit Bayer BGBG/GRGR)
                Size: Stepwise 16x16 - 16376x16376 with step 1/1
        [33]: 'pGEE' (14-bit Bayer GBGB/RGRG Packed)
                Size: Stepwise 16x16 - 16376x16376 with step 1/1
        [34]: 'GB14' (14-bit Bayer GBGB/RGRG)
                Size: Stepwise 16x16 - 16376x16376 with step 1/1
        [35]: 'pgEE' (14-bit Bayer GRGR/BGBG Packed)
                Size: Stepwise 16x16 - 16376x16376 with step 1/1
        [36]: 'GR14' (14-bit Bayer GRGR/BGBG)
                Size: Stepwise 16x16 - 16376x16376 with step 1/1
        [37]: 'pREE' (14-bit Bayer RGRG/GBGB Packed)
                Size: Stepwise 16x16 - 16376x16376 with step 1/1
        [38]: 'RG14' (14-bit Bayer RGRG/GBGB)
                Size: Stepwise 16x16 - 16376x16376 with step 1/1
        [39]: 'GREY' (8-bit Greyscale)
                Size: Stepwise 16x16 - 16376x16376 with step 1/1
        [40]: 'Y10P' (10-bit Greyscale (MIPI Packed))
                Size: Stepwise 16x16 - 16376x16376 with step 1/1
        [41]: 'Y10 ' (10-bit Greyscale)
                Size: Stepwise 16x16 - 16376x16376 with step 1/1
        [42]: 'Y12P' (12-bit Greyscale (MIPI Packed))
                Size: Stepwise 16x16 - 16376x16376 with step 1/1
        [43]: 'Y12 ' (12-bit Greyscale)
                Size: Stepwise 16x16 - 16376x16376 with step 1/1
        [44]: 'Y14P' (14-bit Greyscale (MIPI Packed))
                Size: Stepwise 16x16 - 16376x16376 with step 1/1
        [45]: 'Y14 ' (14-bit Greyscale)
                Size: Stepwise 16x16 - 16376x16376 with step 1/1
```

Why will v4l2rtspserver not recognize the camera at /dev/video0?